# Match data to nearest time value by id

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have generated a series of hourly time stamps with:

```
intervals <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-20 00:00:00", tz = 'America/Los_Angeles'), as.POSIXct("2018-01-20 03:00:00", tz = 'America/Los_Angeles'), by="hour")

> intervals
[1] "2018-01-20 00:00:00 PST" "2018-01-20 01:00:00 PST" "2018-01-20 02:00:00 PST"
[4] "2018-01-20 03:00:00 PST"
```

Given a dataset with messy and unevenly spaced timestamps, how would one match time values from that dataset to the closest hourly timestamp by `id`, and remove other timestamps in between?  For example:

```
> test
                         time      id     amount
312   2018-01-20 00:02:14 PST       1 54.9508346
8652  2018-01-20 00:54:41 PST       2 30.5557992
13809 2018-01-20 01:19:27 PST       3 90.5459248
586   2018-01-20 00:03:35 PST       1 79.7635973
9077  2018-01-20 00:56:37 PST       2 75.5356406
21546 2018-01-20 02:25:05 PST       3 36.6017705
7275  2018-01-20 00:47:45 PST       1 12.7618139
12768 2018-01-20 01:15:30 PST       2 72.4465838
1172  2018-01-20 00:08:01 PST       3 81.0468155
24106 2018-01-20 03:04:10 PST       1  0.8615881
14464 2018-01-20 01:25:04 PST       2 49.8718743
15344 2018-01-20 01:29:30 PST       3 85.0054113
14255 2018-01-20 01:23:22 PST       1 34.5093891
21565 2018-01-20 02:25:40 PST       2 69.0175725
15602 2018-01-20 01:31:32 PST       3 61.8602426
```

Would produce:

```
> output
             interval id     amount
1 2018-01-20 01:00:00  1 12.7618139
2          2018-01-20  1 54.9508346
3 2018-01-20 03:00:00  1  0.8615881
4 2018-01-20 01:00:00  2 75.5356400
5 2018-01-20 02:00:00  2 69.0175700
6          2018-01-20  3 81.0468200
7 2018-01-20 01:00:00  3 90.5459200
8 2018-01-20 02:00:00  3 36.6017700
```

I understand that there exists a possible solution in `data.table`

```
setDT(reference)[data, refvalue, roll = "nearest", on = "datetime"]
```

with `roll = nearest`, but how would one keep find the nearest match in `intervals` for every `id` in `test` and retain the `amount` attribute ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Here is the sample data:

```
 dput(test)
structure(list(time = c("2018-01-20 00:02:14 PST", "2018-01-20 00:54:41 PST", 
"2018-01-20 01:19:27 PST", "2018-01-20 00:03:35 PST", "2018-01-20 00:56:37 PST", 
"2018-01-20 02:25:05 PST", "2018-01-20 00:47:45 PST", "2018-01-20 01:15:30 PST", 
"2018-01-20 00:08:01 PST", "2018-01-20 03:04:10 PST", "2018-01-20 01:25:04 PST", 
"2018-01-20 01:29:30 PST", "2018-01-20 01:23:22 PST", "2018-01-20 02:25:40 PST", 
"2018-01-20 01:31:32 PST"), id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), amount = c(54.9508346011862, 30.5557992309332, 
90.5459248460829, 79.763597343117, 75.5356406327337, 36.6017704829574, 
12.7618139144033, 72.4465838400647, 81.0468154959381, 0.861588073894382, 
49.8718742514029, 85.0054113194346, 34.5093891490251, 69.0175724914297, 
61.8602426256984)), .Names = c("time", "id", "amount"), row.names = c(312L, 
8652L, 13809L, 586L, 9077L, 21546L, 7275L, 12768L, 1172L, 24106L, 
14464L, 15344L, 14255L, 21565L, 15602L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In the desired out row with amount of `34.5093891` for `id == 1` is missing while that is the closest observation to the second hour. Why is that?

Comment: @Jaap for `34.5093891` the timestamp is `2018-01-20 01:23:22` which is closer to `"2018-01-20 01:00:00 PST"` rather to `"2018-01-20 02:00:00 PST"`. There is no match for `"2018-01-20 02:00:00 PST"` in the first id at all

Comment: @DavidArenburg That is your interpretation. Based on the sentence *how would one keep find the nearest match in intervals for every id in test and retain the amount attribute* I would think otherwise; I like to hear some clarification from OP. At the moment, that sentence and the desired output contradict each other (imo at least).

Comment: Actually, they are both valid answers. Technically David  is correct because   01:23:22 is closer to 1, and his answer will produce the desired output given a very limited sample.  But @Jaap is correct because every id has four corresponding "best" matches.  In reality the dataset has more or less time intervals every 5-10 minutes per id, so J's answer is very applicable in this case. Thank you

Comment: @Jaap How is that my interpretation? I'm looking on the desired output

Comment: @the_darkside so what is your *real* desired output?

Comment: @DavidArenburg As I said in my previous comment, the output and the description (seem to) contradict each other. You looked at the output and I looked at the desciption to get to a solution. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to join inside `j` with `data.table`:

```
# convert 'test' to a 'data.table' first with 'setDT'
# and convert the 'time'-column tot a datetime format
setDT(test)[, time := as.POSIXct(time)][]

# preform the join
test[, .SD[.(time = intervals), on = .(time), roll = 'nearest'], by = id]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     id                time     amount
>  1:  1 2018-01-20 00:00:00 54.9508346
>  2:  1 2018-01-20 01:00:00 12.7618139
>  3:  1 2018-01-20 02:00:00 34.5093891
>  4:  1 2018-01-20 03:00:00  0.8615881
>  5:  2 2018-01-20 00:00:00 30.5557992
>  6:  2 2018-01-20 01:00:00 75.5356406
>  7:  2 2018-01-20 02:00:00 69.0175725
>  8:  2 2018-01-20 03:00:00 69.0175725
>  9:  3 2018-01-20 00:00:00 81.0468155
> 10:  3 2018-01-20 01:00:00 90.5459248
> 11:  3 2018-01-20 02:00:00 36.6017705
> 12:  3 2018-01-20 03:00:00 36.6017705
> ```

In the above approach some `amount`-values are assigned to more than one `time` by `id`. If you don't want that and only want to keep the ones which are the closest to a `time` you could refine the approach as follows:

```
test[, r := rowid(id)
     ][, .SD[.(time = intervals)
             , on = .(time)
             , roll = 'nearest'
             , .(time, amount, r, time_diff = abs(x.time - i.time))
             ][, .SD[which.min(time_diff)], by = r]
       , by = id][, c('r','time_diff') := NULL][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>     id                time     amount
>  1:  1 2018-01-20 00:00:00 54.9508346
>  2:  1 2018-01-20 01:00:00 12.7618139
>  3:  1 2018-01-20 02:00:00 34.5093891
>  4:  1 2018-01-20 03:00:00  0.8615881
>  5:  2 2018-01-20 00:00:00 30.5557992
>  6:  2 2018-01-20 01:00:00 75.5356406
>  7:  2 2018-01-20 02:00:00 69.0175725
>  8:  3 2018-01-20 00:00:00 81.0468155
>  9:  3 2018-01-20 01:00:00 90.5459248
> 10:  3 2018-01-20 02:00:00 36.6017705
> ```

Comment: I don't think this matches desired output though

Comment: @DavidArenburg It might be that OP forgot some rows in the desired output. At least it gives the same output as chinsoons12's answer

Comment: chinsoons answer doesn't meet the desired output neither

Comment: @DavidArenburg based on OP's description (*how would one keep find the nearest match in `intervals` for every `id` in `test` and retain the `amount` attribute*) I think this is giving the correct output.

Comment: OP provided the desired output in the question

Comment: agree with @DavidArenburg, will remove my soln

Comment: not sure why but I get `Error in `[.data.frame`(test, , .SD[.(time = intervals), on = .(time),  : 
  unused argument (by = id)`  when I apply that solution.  Any idea why that could be @Jaap?

Comment: @the_darkside you to convert `test` to data.ble with `setDT(test)` first; will add that to my answer

Comment: @the_darkside sorry, I forgot the part of converting `time` in `test` to a data-time format; see the update

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @DavidAurenburg solution, a condensed version:

```
test[, 
    .(amount=amount[which.min(abs(time - round(time, "hour")))]), 
    keyby=.(id, as.character(round(time, "hour")))]
```

---

#### Previous post below didnt match user required output

Maybe you would like to include id in your joins as well. When using nearest, you might get matches from data coming from a few hours ago

```
output <- test[intervals, on=c("id","time"), roll="nearest"]
setorder(output, id, time)
output
#                    time id     amount
#  1: 2018-01-20 00:00:00  1 54.9508346
#  2: 2018-01-20 01:00:00  1 12.7618139
#  3: 2018-01-20 02:00:00  1 34.5093891
#  4: 2018-01-20 03:00:00  1  0.8615881
#  5: 2018-01-20 00:00:00  2 30.5557992
#  6: 2018-01-20 01:00:00  2 75.5356406
#  7: 2018-01-20 02:00:00  2 69.0175725
#  8: 2018-01-20 03:00:00  2 69.0175725
#  9: 2018-01-20 00:00:00  3 81.0468155
# 10: 2018-01-20 01:00:00  3 90.5459248
# 11: 2018-01-20 02:00:00  3 36.6017705
# 12: 2018-01-20 03:00:00  3 36.6017705
```

Hope to see a more elegant use of the data.table to solve this.

data:

```
intervals <- CJ(time=seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-20 00:00:00"), 
    as.POSIXct("2018-01-20 03:00:00"), 
    by="hour"), id=1:3)

test <- fread("time,id,amount
2018-01-20 00:02:14 PST,1,54.9508346
2018-01-20 00:54:41 PST,2,30.5557992
2018-01-20 01:19:27 PST,3,90.5459248
2018-01-20 00:03:35 PST,1,79.7635973
2018-01-20 00:56:37 PST,2,75.5356406
2018-01-20 02:25:05 PST,3,36.6017705
2018-01-20 00:47:45 PST,1,12.7618139
2018-01-20 01:15:30 PST,2,72.4465838
2018-01-20 00:08:01 PST,3,81.0468155
2018-01-20 03:04:10 PST,1,0.8615881
2018-01-20 01:25:04 PST,2,49.8718743
2018-01-20 01:29:30 PST,3,85.0054113
2018-01-20 01:23:22 PST,1,34.5093891
2018-01-20 02:25:40 PST,2,69.0175725
2018-01-20 01:31:32 PST,3,61.8602426")[,
    time:=as.POSIXct(time)]
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this using lubridate?

```
library(lubridate);library(dplyr)
test$time<-ymd_hms(test$time)
test$HTime=round_date(test$time,unit="hour")
test$DiffTime=abs(test$time-test$HTime)
result=test%>%group_by(id,HTime)%>%summarize(amount=amount[DiffTime==min(DiffTime)])
result


 # A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups: id [?]
     id HTime               amount
  <dbl> <dttm>               <dbl>
1  1.00 2018-01-20 00:00:00 55.0  
2  1.00 2018-01-20 01:00:00 12.8  
3  1.00 2018-01-20 03:00:00  0.862
4  2.00 2018-01-20 01:00:00 75.5  
5  2.00 2018-01-20 02:00:00 69.0  
6  3.00 2018-01-20 00:00:00 81.0  
7  3.00 2018-01-20 01:00:00 90.5  
8  3.00 2018-01-20 02:00:00 36.6
```