# Rolling join by condition

Tags: r, timestamp, dplyr, data.table

I am referencing a [recent, well-answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457575/match-data-to-nearest-time-value-by-id), concerning matching timestamps with `data.table`.

Given a set of equally spaced ten-minute intervals:

```
intervals <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-20 00:00:00", tz = 'America/Los_Angeles'), as.POSIXct("2018-01-20 03:00:00", tz = 'America/Los_Angeles'), by= "10 mins")
```

And data to match on the closest intervals by `time`:

```
> head(test)
                         time id   amount
312   2018-01-20 00:02:14 PST  1 54.95083
8652  2018-01-20 00:54:41 PST  2 30.55580
13809 2018-01-20 01:19:27 PST  3 90.54592
586   2018-01-20 00:03:35 PST  1 79.76360
9077  2018-01-20 00:56:37 PST  2 75.53564
21546 2018-01-20 02:25:05 PST  3 36.60177
```

How would one only include matches in `test$time` that are within a 5-minute range of the closest given intervals *and* make sure that there is only one match per interval record (by `id`)?

```
setDT(test)[, time := as.POSIXct(time)][]
test[, .SD[.(time = intervals), on = .(time), roll = 'nearest'], by = id]
```

For example, the above code produces an **unexpected result**:

```
> head(test[, .SD[.(time = intervals), on = .(time), roll = 'nearest'], by = id], n = 10)
    id                time    amount
 1:  1 2018-01-20 00:00:00 0.8615881
 2:  1 2018-01-20 00:10:00 0.8615881
 3:  1 2018-01-20 00:20:00 0.8615881
 4:  1 2018-01-20 00:30:00 0.8615881
 5:  1 2018-01-20 00:40:00 0.8615881
 6:  1 2018-01-20 00:50:00 0.8615881
 7:  1 2018-01-20 01:00:00 0.8615881
 8:  1 2018-01-20 01:10:00 0.8615881
 9:  1 2018-01-20 01:20:00 0.8615881
10:  1 2018-01-20 01:30:00 0.8615881
```

Whereas the **expected output** would be:

```
    id                time    amount
 1:  1 2018-01-20 00:00:00 54.9508346
 2:  1 2018-01-20 00:50:00 12.7618139
 3:  1 2018-01-20 01:20:00 34.5093891
 4:  1 2018-01-20 03:00:00 0.8615881
 5:  2 2018-01-20 00:50:00 30.5557992
 6:  2 2018-01-20 01:00:00 75.5356406
 7:  2 2018-01-20 01:20:00 72.4465838
 8:  2 2018-01-20 01:30:00 49.8718743
 9:  2 2018-01-20 02:30:00 69.0175725
10:  3 2018-01-20 00:10:00 81.0468155
11:  3 2018-01-20 01:20:00 90.5459248
12:  3 2018-01-20 01:30:00 85.0054113
13:  3 2018-01-20 02:30:00 36.60177053
```

Note that if the closest match in `intervals` is more than 5 minutes away (difftime between interval and test$time > 5 mins), the records should be excluded altogether in the output.

How would one add these conditions in `data.table`, `dplyr` or base R to match the expected output?

Suggestions on how to get the difference between `test$time` and the nearest matching interval in the output would also be helpful.  Hope that makes sense.

`test` data below:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(time = c("2018-01-20 00:02:14 PST", "2018-01-20 00:54:41 PST", 
"2018-01-20 01:19:27 PST", "2018-01-20 00:03:35 PST", "2018-01-20 00:56:37 PST", 
"2018-01-20 02:25:05 PST", "2018-01-20 00:47:45 PST", "2018-01-20 01:15:30 PST", 
"2018-01-20 00:08:01 PST", "2018-01-20 03:04:10 PST", "2018-01-20 01:25:04 PST", 
"2018-01-20 01:29:30 PST", "2018-01-20 01:23:22 PST", "2018-01-20 02:25:40 PST", 
"2018-01-20 01:31:32 PST"), id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), amount = c(54.9508346011862, 30.5557992309332, 
90.5459248460829, 79.763597343117, 75.5356406327337, 36.6017704829574, 
12.7618139144033, 72.4465838400647, 81.0468154959381, 0.861588073894382, 
49.8718742514029, 85.0054113194346, 34.5093891490251, 69.0175724914297, 
61.8602426256984)), .Names = c("time", "id", "amount"), row.names = c(312L, 
8652L, 13809L, 586L, 9077L, 21546L, 7275L, 12768L, 1172L, 24106L, 
14464L, 15344L, 14255L, 21565L, 15602L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution (which is an adaptation of [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48458277/2204410)):

```
ref <- CJ(id = test$id, time = intervals, unique = TRUE)

ref[test
    , on = .(id, time)
    , roll = 'nearest'
    , .(id, time = x.time, amount = i.amount, time_diff = abs(x.time - i.time))
    ][, .SD[which.min(time_diff)], by = .(id, time)
      ][order(id, time)][, time_diff := NULL][]
```

which gives the desired output:

> ```
>     id                time     amount
>  1:  1 2018-01-20 00:00:00 54.9508346
>  2:  1 2018-01-20 00:50:00 12.7618139
>  3:  1 2018-01-20 01:20:00 34.5093891
>  4:  1 2018-01-20 03:00:00  0.8615881
>  5:  2 2018-01-20 00:50:00 30.5557992
>  6:  2 2018-01-20 01:00:00 75.5356406
>  7:  2 2018-01-20 01:20:00 72.4465838
>  8:  2 2018-01-20 01:30:00 49.8718743
>  9:  2 2018-01-20 02:30:00 69.0175725
> 10:  3 2018-01-20 00:10:00 81.0468155
> 11:  3 2018-01-20 01:20:00 90.5459248
> 12:  3 2018-01-20 01:30:00 85.0054113
> 13:  3 2018-01-20 02:30:00 36.6017705
> ```

---

Used data:

```
test <- structure(list(time = c("2018-01-20 00:02:14 PST", "2018-01-20 00:54:41 PST", "2018-01-20 01:19:27 PST", "2018-01-20 00:03:35 PST", "2018-01-20 00:56:37 PST", "2018-01-20 02:25:05 PST", "2018-01-20 00:47:45 PST", "2018-01-20 01:15:30 PST", "2018-01-20 00:08:01 PST", "2018-01-20 03:04:10 PST", "2018-01-20 01:25:04 PST", "2018-01-20 01:29:30 PST", "2018-01-20 01:23:22 PST", "2018-01-20 02:25:40 PST", "2018-01-20 01:31:32 PST"), id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                       amount = c(54.9508346011862, 30.5557992309332, 90.5459248460829, 79.763597343117, 75.5356406327337, 36.6017704829574, 12.7618139144033, 72.4465838400647, 81.0468154959381, 0.861588073894382, 49.8718742514029, 85.0054113194346, 34.5093891490251, 69.0175724914297, 61.8602426256984)),
                  .Names = c("time", "id", "amount"), row.names = c(312L, 8652L, 13809L, 586L, 9077L, 21546L, 7275L, 12768L, 1172L, 24106L, 14464L, 15344L, 14255L, 21565L, 15602L), class = "data.frame")

intervals <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-20 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-01-20 03:00:00"), by = "10 mins")

setDT(test)[, time := as.POSIXct(time)][]
```

NOTE: I used no timezone in creating the `intervals` vector because that gives me the same timezone as in the `test` dataset (`time := as.POSIXct(time)` sets the timezone to `CET` for me).

Comment: Thanks @Jaap, strangely though I am getting an output of 3 rows : `id                time     amount
1:  1 2018-01-20 03:00:00  0.8615881
2:  2 2018-01-20 03:00:00 69.0175725
3:  3 2018-01-20 03:00:00 36.6017705`

Comment: Yes, first I convert time to PosixCT with `setDT(test)[, time := as.POSIXct(time)][]`  then run the above code.  The output is 3 rows, so I am unsure how you are getting your output

Comment: this has to do with timezones, my apologies

Comment: @the_darkside What is the output of `Sys.timezone()` for you?

Comment: I think I solved the timezone issue, but what is meant here by `x.time` and `i.amount` ?  what do variables x and i represent?

Comment: @the_darkside `x.` and `i.` refer to the data.table's used in the join where `x.` refers to the first one (in this case `ref`) and `i.` refers to the second one which used in `i` (in this case `test`)

Comment: I just want to get a sense of how `time_diff` is calculated, because when I apply this on a larger dataset, where there are, for example, records every minute, the code is still not producing one match per `id` per 10-minute interval

Comment: @the_darkside Could you include an example in the question that illustrates that problem?

Comment: In essence what I am saying is that there can be multiple `min(time_diff)`  and if they are the same, they will be counted twice.  So a `which.distinct.min(time_diff)` should be added, but I am not sure how translates into `data.table`

Comment: @the_darkside You could try `which.min(time_diff)[1]` or wrap the resulting *data.table* in `unique`